# Custom grid - Remove link on rows

Tags: adminhtml, grid, custom, link

I have a custom grid, that get data from my custom database.

Right now it is linking is dead and i will get a 404-not found.

Is there a way to remove the link on the rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create below method in you block grid class:

`YourModule_Adminhtml_Block_XXX_YYY_Grid extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, happy coding ... :)

Comment: How we can do it for magento 2 admin grid?

Comment: @PramodKharade I didn't worked on M2, but found related forum [***on this link***](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Custom-grid-Remove-link-on-rows/td-p/28084), it might be helps you.